Estimating the value of information for determining when to stop an experiment
Suppose that there are two parameters $p_1, p_2 \in [0, 1]$, and you begin with an uninformative prior $\textrm{Beta}(1, 1)$ for both of them. An experiment has been running for $d$ days. On each day you have drawn $n$ samples from $\textrm{Bernoulli}(p_1)$ and $n$ samples from $\textrm{Bernoulli}(p_2)$. You receive a payout of the sum of your observations. So in total you have $dn$ data points $X_{1,1}, X_{1,2}, \dots, X_{1, dn}$ that are i.i.d $\textrm{Bernoulli}(p_1)$, which is worth $\sum_{i=1}^{dn} X_{1,i}$, and you also have data and value for $p_2$.
For simplicity, let's say that on any day on the remaining $D$ days, you either sample $n$ from both or you stop the experiment and keep sampling $2n$ observations from $p_2$ each day. You want to estimate the expected risk of sampling $n$ from both for another day. The risk on the next day is the value of $$\left[\textrm{Binom}(n, p_1) + \textrm{Binom}(n, p_2)\right] - \textrm{Binom}(2n, p_2),$$
and we can estimate the distribution of the risk from the posterior distributions of $p_1, p_2$.
But this formula for the risk excludes the value of the information that we learn from sampling for an extra day. Is there a way of estimating the value of the information in this case? I could use the current posterior distribution to draw samples of tomorrow's observations under both decisions, and look at how they would impact the risk estimation on the day after tomorrow? But this seems overcomplicated.
A standard metric for the information gain is the Kullback-Leibler divergence between the distributions before and after we get the data update. (Rauber, Braun and Burns, 2008) shows that the KL-divergence is not defined for a pair of Beta distributions, but other distance measures like the Bhattacharya distance are defined. But with a difference measure, is there even an approximate way of saying how much it would be worth in a setting like this?
If we allowed ourselves to split tomorrow's $2n$ samples between the two methods however we like then there are methods like Thompson sampling that we could use - we would sample $2nP(p_1 > p_2 \mid \textrm{data})$ from $p_1$ and the rest from $p_2$. This should give a reasonable tradeoff between exploration and exploitation, but for a practical application, where we have a backlog of things that we want to test and would prefer it if there were no concurrent tests, it's better to make a decision once we are confident that there is a risk from continuing and there's little chance of our decision being overturned by future data.

This is related to, but not quite, a Bayesian bandit, which is something the Gittins index solves optimally. Even if it's not optimal here, it still captures the "value of information" vs. "good quality now" tradeoff in a possibly helpful way.

Thanks @Ziv that looks very helpful

This is not quite a bandit problem, because you can't switch between actions, you just decide one time to switch. To me this reads as a Robbins-ian testing problem: choose a confidence level $\delta$ and design a stopping time $\tau$ for a test such that if $p_2 > p_1,$ then $\tau$ is minimised, subject to the false positive rate being no more than $\delta$. Then you can choose $\delta$ to optimise, say, the mean reward. I'd look at work on sequential testing, the typical optimal strategy should lose about $1/(p_2 - p_1) \log(D \log(1/p_2 - p_1))$ if $n = 1$.

I guess if you want a general index that balances the reward and the gain of information, there's some interesting work of Foster et al. that tries to construct such a setup for sequential decision making (which encompasses bandtis), but I don't know if it transfers well to this setup. Maybe that is helpful. I should mention that my viewpoint is much more frequentist, so I'm probably not up to scratch on the Bayesian understanding of such problems.

Thanks @stochasticboy321 I will definitely check out these suggestions.
I should have made it clearer in the question that I'm not too concerned with false positives as long as the impact is minimal, which is why I'm interested in the expected risk in particular. If $p_1 = p_2$ and I made a firm decision to go with $p_2$ then the risk would be $0$
